# How to make a php cookie with jquery

Tags: php, jquery

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', '<?php echo $id; ?>', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
```

This is what I tried, first `$_COOKIE["the_cookie"]` doesn't output, anything, second I want it to expire in 10 minutes not 7 days, also I want to use it in future in an extern file, so I would like to know how to set the $id into a jquery variable and then use the cookie function with the variable.

Comment: PHP is a server side language, once executed/complied the variables cease to exist. You'll need to put this script file inside a PHP file to access the variables.

Comment: I know, and it still doesn't outputs the cookie

Comment: You're setting the cookie with jQuery (well, the $.cookie plugin) which happens on the client, after PHP has packed up its bags and gone home for tea... PHP won't have access to that cookie until you reload the page; `$_COOKIE['the_cookie']` won't exist before then.

Comment: ik, that, but as I said it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the cookie using vanilla JS:

```
var PHPid = "<?php echo $id; ?>"; //store PHP id in JS variable
var date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime()+(10*1000)); //expires in 10 mins
var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
document.cookie = "id="+PHPid+expires+"; path=/";
```

Once this has been set, it can be retrieved in PHP using the following:

```
$cookie = $_COOKIE['id'];
```

Comment: Works perfect <3 But there is one tiny proble, the cookie expires in 10 seconds :/

Comment: Change the (10*1000) to (10*60*1000)